# C# Sharepoint Uploader status?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

i have the following code to upload file to my companies SharePoint server.
How can I get the status of the upload?

```
public void UploadDocumentContent(ClientContext ctx, string libraryName, string filePath)
    {
        Web web = ctx.Web;

        FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();

        // The next line of code causes an exception to be thrown for files larger than 2 MB.
        newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        newFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        // Get instances to the given library.
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);

        // Add file to the library.
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
        ctx.Load(uploadFile);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "the status of the upload"? Do you mean what percentage complete it is or if it succeeds or fails?  If it fails I would assume an exception would be thrown.

Comment: succeed or failed would suffice...